# Why do we always consider the area of inner solenoid while calculating the mutual inductance of two coaxial solenoids?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

While we know that flux linked to an area is the dot product of the area vector of the loop(and not the actual area encountering the field lines) and the magnetic field linked to it, why then do we consider the area of inner solenoid while deriving the expression of mutual inductance of the outer solenoid. Most of the textbooks say that since magnetic field lines produced by inner solenoid are totally confined within that solenoid hence the effective area of outer solenoid linked to this flux is numerically equal to the area of inner solenoid. This sounds really contradictory to the definition of magnetic flux.[image]

Comment: The key is in the word *mutual*.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate the inductance of either solenoid, you calculate the total flux in each solenoid.  In order to calculate the mutual inductance you need to calculate either (a) the flux through the smaller solenoid due to a current through the larger solenoid or (b) the flux through the larger solenoid due to a current in the smaller solenoid.   In (a) all that matters is the flux through the smaller solenoid.  In (b) there is flux only through the smaller solenoid.  The fact that in (b) there is flux elsewhere, is irrelevant.